# Python university exam,

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I have to create a function able to calculate the average of products built by various lines of production in a range of time.

EXAMPLE:

```
input = [('line1', 0, 5), ('line1', 0, 6), ('line2', 0, 3), ('line1', 0, 5), ('line3', 0, 4), ('line2', 0, 9), ('line3', 0, -1), ('line2', 0, 9), ('line2', 0, 10), ('line3', 0, 12), ('line1', 0, 1), ('line3', 0, 16)]

output = {'line1': 4.25, 'line2': 7.75, 'line3': 7.75}
```

I cannot calculate the average of each line because i don't know how to determine the period between two days.

EDIT: I'm sorry, i think i haven't explained the problem well. This is not an actual exam, it's a previous exam given by my professor to train.

Comment: please add what yo have tried. Also, what is the actual calculation to get 4.25 for line 1?

Comment: See [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: Where does the range of time come into play? From the output, it appears you just want the average value of each line.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this isn't for an actual "exam", because getting outside help with an exam question is usually a violation of a school's honor code, but I'll give you the benefit of the doubt.

I wrote this very simple version since you're new to Python and it should be relatively easy to follow the logic on each line.

```
data = [('line1', 0, 5), ('line1', 0, 6), ('line2', 0, 3), ('line1', 0, 5), ('line3', 0, 4), ('line2', 0, 9), ('line3', 0, -1), ('line2', 0, 9), ('line2', 0, 10), ('line3', 0, 12), ('line1', 0, 1), ('line3', 0, 16)]

results = {}

for item in data:
  line = item[0]
  if not line in results:
    results[line] = {}
    results[line]["count"] = 1
    results[line]["total"] = item[2]
  else:
    results[line]["count"] += 1
    results[line]["total"] += item[2]

averaged_results = {}

for line in results:
  averaged_results[line] = results[line]["total"] / float(results[line]["count"])

print(averaged_results)
```

You can [run this code](https://repl.it/repls/SqueakyClearUnderstanding) to verify it works and refactor it. There are "better" ways to do this that are more concise and efficient, but this solution is designed for a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

You need to group your data by the line:

```
import itertools
input = [('line1', 0, 5), ('line1', 0, 6), ('line2', 0, 3), ('line1', 0, 5), ('line3', 0, 4), ('line2', 0, 9), ('line3', 0, -1), ('line2', 0, 9), ('line2', 0, 10), ('line3', 0, 12), ('line1', 0, 1), ('line3', 0, 16)]
new_result = {a:[c for *_, c in b] for a, b in itertools.groupby(sorted(input, key=lambda x:x[0]), key=lambda x:x[0])}
final_result = {a:round(sum(b)/float(len(b)), 2) for a, b in new_result.items()}
```

Output:

```
{'line1': 4.25, 'line3': 7.75, 'line2': 7.75}
```

Edit: simpler option with `collections.defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
for a, _, b in input:
  d[a].append(b)

final_result = {a:round(sum(b)/float(len(b)), 2) for a, b in d.items()}
```

Output:

```
{'line1': 4.25, 'line3': 7.75, 'line2': 7.75}
```

Comment: Considering the question is being asked by a beginner, I think this solution may be overly complex.